# Using Class from aspx page

Tags: asp.net

I have created a class containing a couple of strings.
(I want to override the `ToString()` for this class eventually, to apply custom formatting).

This class gets instantiated in the code-behind .cs file.

My question is how do I pass values to this object from the .aspx page?

I tried typing a . after the object's name,
but Intellisense didn't show the class' member names as it usually would.

If I simply add some text as the property, I get a run-time error:

```
Cannot create an object of type ... from its string representation
```

Any ideas how to do this?

What is the correct syntax to use?

Thanks

Comment: Why do you need to pass values from the aspx?

Comment: The class is in shared code (a user-control), and every page will use it....

Comment: You could assign the values from codebehind anyway